# Docker inside Nginx server does not works with HTTPS?

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, https, docker-compose

I have **Ubuntu 18.04** machine, where I set up **Nginx with LetsEncrypt SSL** certificate. 
Inside application I runned **Node.js API with Docker**.

> Client -> Nginx (with SSL) -> Docker (SSL doesn't work) -> Node.js app

For running I uses **Docker-compose** with certain code:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - 'database:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}'
    networks:
      - application_name

  modules:
    image: node:12.14.1
    working_dir: '/app'
    entrypoint: 'npm'
    volumes:
      - './package.json:/app/package.json'
      - 'node_modules:/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - application_name
    env_file:
      - .env

  back:
    image: node:9.5.0
    working_dir: '/app'
    command: 'npm run start:app'
    ports:
      - '${APP_1_PORT}:${APP_1_PORT}'
      - '${APP_2_PORT}:${APP_2_PORT}'
    networks:
      - application_name
    volumes:
      - './docs/:/app/docs'
      - './src/:/app/src'
      - './package.json:/app/package.json'
      - './package-lock.json:/app/package-lock.json'
      - './tsconfig.json:/app/tsconfig.json'
      - 'node_modules:/app/node_modules'
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Nginx works with HTTPS, but Docker application does not ( `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`).

I read that Docker does not see certificates, and this is the reason of issue. I saw solutions, but on that examples Nginx has been inside the Docker, not vice versa. How it can be solved for this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your nginx configs /

Answer (score 0):

If you would like that docker to handle the ssl cert and termination then you need to share the SSL certs with the docker application instances (this app back).

Another alternative is to terminate the SSL connection by NGINX and forward an HTTP connection to docker applications.